# Elasticsearch stops working

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

This is my system:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nginx 1.14.0
- MySQL 5.7.25
- Magento 2.3

I installed elasticsearch and it worked fine but it gave me this error and I do not know how to fix it:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Log Errors:

**elasticsearch.log**

> ...
>
> [2019-02-11T11:10:57,773][WARN ][o.e.c.InternalClusterInfoService] [J0f87iQ] Failed to update node information for ClusterInfoUpdateJob within 15s timeout

**gc.log.0.current**

> 2019-02-11T11:10:56.503+0100: 148.205: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.9227318 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.6230841 seconds

**elasticsearch_deprecation.log**

> [2019-02-11T11:04:49,724][WARN ][o.e.d.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [J0f87iQ] the default number of shards will change from [5] to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeNeK.png) in 7.0.0; if you wish to continue using the default of [5] shards, you must manage this on the create index request or with an index template
>
> [2019-02-11T11:04:50,788][WARN ][o.e.d.i.m.AllFieldMapper ] [J0f87iQ] [_all] is deprecated in 6.0+ and will be removed in 7.0. As a replacement, you can use [copy_to] on mapping fields to create your own catch all field.

Comment: what kind of error you are facing? you not mentioned that error.

Comment: I have edited my question with the messages I have in the elasticsearch log files

Comment: since the elasticsearch process has been killed, you might find some hints in the syslog around the time where elasticsearch crashed. It might be a memory issue.

Comment: Where can I see if there is a memory problem?